# unable to mount HTC One

Tags: 14.04

I'm currently on ubuntu 14.04 on my vaio pro 13 
It has intel i5 haswell. Both of my usb ports are 3.0.
When I plug in my HTC One it gives error

'Couldn't find matching udev device.'

I did a lot of googling but none of the guide with mtp-tools helped